# Applying classes to d3 chart in react application using css modules

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, css-modules

After much looking around, i had to ask this question. I have been using css modules in my react application. I decided to have a d3 component. However, after much research, I am still not able to find a way to load css classes to my d3 application. Following is my directory container:

```
app/containers/Chart
├── ChartContainer.js
├── flare.js
└── styles.css
```

My css modules `styles.css` looks like this:

```
.reset{
    border: none;
    background: transparent;
    color: #d0021b;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.reset:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.node circle {
    fill: #fff;
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 1px;
}

.node text {
    font: 14px sans-serif;
}

.link {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #ccc;
    stroke-width: 1px;
}
```

`ChartContainer.js` has all the logic to render the d3 chart. It mostly resembles the example here: https://codepen.io/brendandougan/pen/PpEzRp

I am not sure how can I proceed. Worst case, I think i might just import the css on top of my `index.js` file. However, that seems a dumb way to me.

Can anyway help me if they have found a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this for d3.

```
import '!style-loader!css-loader!./styles.css';
```

Alternatively you can load the css-module like this also but possibility is when refresh of d3 happens styles need to be re-loaded. (this depend on how d3 is loaded into react, for [reference](https://medium.com/@tibotiber/react-d3-js-balancing-performance-developer-experience-4da35f912484) )

```
import sty from './styles.css'    
//inside render
<svg className={[sty.reset,sty.node].join(' ')}>
</svg>
```